# How to hide header/footer of a #+begin_src block in Emacs Org Mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How to hide header/footer of a `#+begin_src` block in Emacs Org Mode?
For example, the `org-hide-emphasis-markers t` will do it for various kinds of other things in Org Mode, but how to do it for header/footer of a `#+begin_src` block?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future googlers: I found this great package, https://github.com/minad/org-modern. This does what I want and even better.